# SQL Random Select No Repeat

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a set that looks like this:

```
staffID clientID eventID
s1      c1       e1c1
s1      c1       e2c1
s1      c2       e1c2
s2      c3       e1c3
s2      c4       e1c4
s2      c5       e1c5
s2      c6       e1c6
```

I want to select from this list two random clients for each staff.  The clients should not repeat.  This is not an issue for s2 but can be a problem for s1:
s1      c1       e1c1
s1      c1       e2c1
s2      c3       e1c3
s2      c5       e1c5
If a client has multiple events with one staff, the client may repeat.

The code I have works great, except for this one aspect (above).

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (
    SELECT eru AS RU, rudesc AS RUName, estaff AS StaffID
    , (CASE
    WHEN cdprogram.prog = client.cprog THEN ('yes: ' + cdprogram.prog)
    WHEN cdprogram.prog <> client.cprog THEN ('no: ' + client.cprog)
    END ) AS 'IsPrimProg'
    , ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eru, estaff ORDER BY NEWID()) 'RowsPerStaff' 
    FROM staff INNER JOIN events ON sid = estaff 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN client ON client.cid = events.ecaseno
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY eru, rudesc, estaff, sfname, slname, cdprogram.prog, client.cprog
    , ecaseno, edate, cdprogram.progdesc, eser
    ) innerquery
    WHERE innerquery.RowsPerStaff <= 2
    ORDER BY RU, StaffID, RowsPerStaff
```

This code works great, it produces two rows for each staff.  But, now I need to fix it so that the same client is not picked twice.

Thank you all!

Comment: you need to use DISTINCT. I'd show you how, if you had included your actual query...

Comment: By the way, in case you are wondering, here is a nice biot of code from a Stackoverflow guru that does the randomizing in the inner select list:  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e_ru, e_staff ORDER BY NEWID()) 'RowsPerStaff'

Comment: Thanks Stevie, DISTINCT in the select of the outer query does the trick.  Awesome.